# What "-movflags frag_keyframe+empty_moov" flag means?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

When encoding video with FFMPEG I am using `-movflags frag_keyframe+empty_moov` - I found it somewhere on the net - and it allows me to get mp4 video stream (without it I get `Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?)` error if I want to stream output somewhere, but it works if I pass output file name `out.mp4` for example). I am asking because this flag also messes with my video somehow and I can't upload it to Twitter for example when using this flag (without it Twitter accepts my video). So it messes up with encoding/format or something else... is there any workaround?

Answer (score 1):

As stated here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8616855/how-to-output-fragmented-mp4-with-ffmpeg

> - frag_keyframe causes fragmented output,
> - empty_moov will cause output to be 100% fragmented; without this the first fragment will be muxed as a short movie (using moov) followed by the rest of the media in fragments

And from the FFmpeg docs you have an explanation about what is fragmentation : https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#mov_002c-mp4_002c-ismv

> Normally, a MOV/MP4 file has all the metadata about all packets stored in one location (written at the end of the file, it can be moved to the start for better playback by adding faststart to the movflags, or using the qt-faststart tool). A fragmented file consists of a number of fragments, where packets and metadata about these packets are stored together. Writing a fragmented file has the advantage that the file is decodable even if the writing is interrupted (while a normal MOV/MP4 is undecodable if it is not properly finished), and it requires less memory when writing very long files (since writing normal MOV/MP4 files stores info about every single packet in memory until the file is closed). The downside is that it is less compatible with other applications.

Answer (score 0):

Trying using this instead:

```
-movflags faststart
```

Comment: It would help if you could explain what this does and how it would solve the question asked.

Comment: This moves the moov atom to the front.  I believe it takes a second pass over the video to accomplish this.  The resulting file is streamable from a webserver to a browser, but if I understand what I read from the other answer you can't stream it directly from ffmpeg without an intermediate file.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8061798/post-processing-in-ffmpeg-to-move-moov-atom-in-mp4-files-qt-faststart